# Styling radio buttons (CSS/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/ptWhn/

```
<pre>
/*HTML*/
`<label class="for_radio"><input type="radio"><span>radio-button-1</span></label>`
`<label class="for_radio"><input type="radio"><span>radio-button-2</span></label>`

/*jQuery*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
if($('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) { 
$(this).closest('label').addClass('active');}
else {
$(this).closest('label').removeClass('active');
}

});
      });

/*CSS*/
.active {
    background: #ffc;
}
</pre>
```

... which works in the sense that the label's background color changes when the radio button is selected, except that I can't figure out how to remove the .active class which changes the background color when one of the radio buttons is UNchecked. And also in jsfiddle, for some reason, the alternate radio button doesn't de-select when the other one is clicked.

The second thing I'm having trouble figuring out why is why I seem to need the .click(function() before the if statement. That is,

```
if($('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) { 
$(this).closest('label').addClass('active');}
```

... doesn't work by itself as a JS snippet. Why?

Would appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: You know `<pre>` != `<script>`, right? You're not going to run anything in <pre> tags, you're just going to print it out with code-like formatting. EDIT: this looks like actually just some weird kind of formatting jsfiddle applied to your code. Will check your js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the if statement,  try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
      $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("active");
      $('input:checked').parent().addClass("active");
   });
});
```

Also, you said "the alternate radio button doesn't de-select when the other one is clicked."

Add name attribute to your inputs, ie: `Name="Group1"`

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, though I tried out your solution http://jsfiddle.net/ptWhn/6/ and couldn't get it working. :/

Comment: @LNA I have updated my answer, I didn't mean for you to remove the document ready and click function, just the If statement. Also in your jsfiddle, you have different name attributes for your inputs, they need to be the same.

Comment: W00t! Works now. Thanks... I had a couple of bugs going on.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, change your pre tags to script tags.

Instead of using an if statement to add and remove the class, why don't you just use `toggleClass()`?

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
   if($('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) { 
      $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active');
   }
});
```

Comment: Heh, yes, I used <pre> tags because i thought you needed them to post code in stackoverflow. Anyway, am going to spend some time looking at these answers... thanks for the quick responses, all!

Comment: @zenith in le last line change this `)};` for `});`, and you can use `$(':radio')` and not `'input[type="radio"]'`

Comment: Update: These answers are only getting me halfway, since I want to have the non-checked radio buttons lose the 'active' class as soon as another radio button is checked -- *not* when the radio button is clicked a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so a few things here.

First, radio buttons in a group need to have the same name.  For example:

```
<label class="for_radio"><input type="radio" name="buttons"><span>radio-button-1</span></label>
<label class="for_radio"><input type="radio" name="buttons"><span>radio-button-2</span></label>
```

This will take care of the issue of the alternate button not deselecting.

To fix the issue of adding and removing your class use jQuery toggleClass:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active');
});
```

There is no need for the if statement. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks -- though this only gets me halfway, since I want to have all the other radio buttons un-highlighted as soon as another radio button is deselected, not when the radio button is clicked for the second time. I tried out your fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptWhn/2/ (Btw, }); is switched up in your example).

Comment: you can use `$(':radio')` and not `'input[type="radio"]'`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and answer the question, since everyone is focused on the fact you're using `<pre>` instead of `<script>`.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function() {
    $('label.active').removeClass('active'); //removes class on old active label
    $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // adds class to new active label
}
```

The reason I did it this way instead of using .toggleClass() is because this will actually work if you have more than two radio buttons.

Comment: Your answer makes sense! Unfortunately I tried it on jsfiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/ptWhn/4/) and it doesn't work. :/ Anyone see where the error might be?

Comment: encapsulate it in .on() event rather than having it as an if statement. I updated my answer, and ur jsFiddle, to reflect this. i also simplified it to use `.parent()` instead of `.closest('label')`, as this is all thats needed.